# Formatting and comparing two dates fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to compare two dates fields while i'm so formatting it but seems not to work. the select statement works but i'm having problem with the where clause

```
SELECT fname
    ,lname
    ,email
    ,rdate_up = CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE())
    ,last_time = CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE())
FROM my_account
WHERE my_account.email = MMColParam
    AND rdate_up = CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE()) < last_time_log = CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE())
```

Comment: is this your real query? as `GETDATE()` will always be the same.

Comment: You should always compare dates as they are (datetime datatypes). This does not affect the display of data. You can safely format the date in your `SELECT` part without converting the dates in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this isn't your real query as comparing `GETDATE()` to itself will always be equal.

If you want to convert dates in the `SELECT` that's fine, I'm guessing you meant this:

```
SELECT fname
    ,lname
    ,email
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), rdate_up)
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), last_time)
FROM my_account
```

But use the actual date values in your `WHERE` clause and get rid of the conversion:

```
WHERE my_account.email = MMColParam
    AND rdate_up < last_time_log
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not compare dates (or anything, for that matter,) after you have converted them to strings.

Compare them before converting to strings.

Convert something to a string only immediately prior to displaying it to a human being.

```
SELECT
    date1,
    date2 = GETDATE(),
    date1toShowToAHumanBeing = CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), date1),
    date2toShowToAHumanBeing = CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), date2)
FROM my_account
WHERE date1 < date2
```

Comment: how do i do that? can yo put it in my answer for me?